# XML access to a child innertext

Tags: c#, .net, xml, innertext

I have this XML:

```
<location>
  <character name="name" mask="pap.png" X="397" Y="60">
    <look reaction="False">
      text1
      <answer>text2</answer>
    </look>
    <talk xml=""/>
  </character>
</location>
```

and I have the access to the node . I have some problem in changing the `text1` and the `text2`. Here my code:

```
node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText = "new_text1";
node.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].InnerText = "new_text2"; //this doesn't work
```

after that my XML looks like:

```
<location>
  <character name="name" mask="pap.png" X="397" Y="60">
    <look reaction="False">text1</look>
    <talk xml=""/>
  </character>
</location>
```

so it cut off the `<answer/>` child. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change `InnerXml`. because of your XML is **Mixed Complex Type** (Complex Type=mixed : xml element can contain attributes, elements, and text) and **DOM** is not aware completely for this ones. your code can be like this:

```
node.ChildNodes[0].InnerXml = "new_text1 <answer>new_text2</answer>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the line `node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText = "new_text1";`

that replace

```
<look reaction="False">
      text1
      <answer>text2</answer>
    </look>
```

then you have already replace the tag `<answer>text2</answer>` from it